# Scala's equivalence to |> in F# or ->> in Clojure

Tags: scala, clojure, f#, operator-keyword

In Scala, when I have this expression

```
f1 ( f2 ( f3 (p)))
```

Is there a way that I can use something like in

F#

```
p |> f3 |> f2 |> f1
```

or Clojure?

```
(->> p f3 f2 f1)
```

Comment: just a note: in clojure its enough to write `(->> p f3 f2 f1)` no need for the extra parens

Comment: @Shlomi: Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to write it yourself without using external libraries,

```
implicit class Pipe[T](x: T) {
  def |> [U](f: T=>U): U = f(x)
}
```

So, this `implicit class` pattern is used for extension methods. It's shorthand for the "pimp my library" pattern:

```
class Pipe[T](x: T) { /*extension methods here*/ }
implicit def anyToPipe[T](x: T) = new Pipe(x)
```

As with any implicit conversion, if the method name is not valid for `T`, but there is a function `T => Pipe` in implicit scope, and the method is valid on `Pipe`, the function (or method here - effectively the same thing) is inserted by the compiler so you get a `Pipe` instance.

```
def |> [U](f: T=>U): U = f(x)
```

This is just a method called `|>` that has a parameter `f` of type `T=>U`, i.e. a `Function1[T,U]`, where `T` is the input type and `U` is the result type. Because we want this to work for any type, we need to make the method type-parameterized on `U` by adding `[U]`. (If we used `T=>Any` instead, our return would be of type `Any`, which wouldn't be much use.) The return value is just the application of the function to the original value, as required.

Answer (score 6):

There is no equivalent to F#'s pipe operator in Scala...

... but there is one in the [scalaz library](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz). And it's also named `|>`. They nicknamed it the "thrush operator".

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def f(s: String) = s.length

"hi" |> f
```

Here's the [scaladoc](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.1.3/scalaz_2.11-7.1.3-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.syntax.IdOps@|>[B](f:A=>B):B).