# How to call a Scala function with a single parameter and write the parameter first

Tags: scala

I have some code that converts the elements of sequences with different functions like that:

```
someSequence map converterFunction
```

However, sometimes I have not a sequence but a single value that is to be passed to the function. For consistency with the other lines I'd like to write it like that

```
someValue applyTo converterFunction
```

So in a way it is like mapping a single value. Of course I can just call the function with the value, I'm just wondering if it is possible to write it similar to the way I proposed.

Comment: As you said, you can wrap it in a collection.  Scala provides map on Option, and TraversableLike (implemented by Seq and the like).  After that you can apply an implicit type conversion to provide yourself with a map or applyTo method.  See https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html for some ideas.  PS I mention that approach more as an fyi rather than a serious suggestion that it is a good idea, as if overused that approach can obsfucate the code rather than help.  Sometimes the obvious direct call is the best.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506410/scalas-equivalence-to-in-f-or-in-clojure/32506489#32506489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with ChrisK that this idea doesn't sound as a good one to me in terms of code readability but if you really want it, you can do it using something like this:

```
implicit final class MapAnyOp[T](val value: T) extends AnyVal {
  def map[R](f: T => R) = f(value)
}

def convert(v: Int): String = Integer.toHexString(v)

println(List(123, 234, 345) map convert)
println(123 map convert)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks pretty much like what I have been looking for. I just think I will not use `map` as a name for the function because it would really be confusing. Maybe `convertWith` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it in a Seq:

```
Seq(someValue) map converterFunction
```

If *someValue* is a custom type/class, you can define an operator that will do that for you instead of having this explicit wrapping.

```
someValue.seq map converterFunction
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting idea. However, I will also have to unwrap it afterwards, so I'm not really convinced of this solution. In the end this is all about beautiful code that looks more or less uniform, at least where it is appropriate.